# Google chart not loading with Angular JS 1.4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I am trying to create graph on my Angular application using [google-chart](https://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/latest/guides/getting-started/)

I tried following this example, but still no success. I mean the graph does not loads, its blank & also there is no error in the console. These are messages obtained in console

[AGC] jsapi loader invoked.  angular.js:12808:18

[AGC] Calling tag helper...  angular.js:12808:18

[AGC] Tag helper returned success.

If I try to run this in plunker or jsfiddle it works as charm

https://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/latest/examples/pie/

Has any one faced  such issue before ? Looking forward for your suggestion

```
angular.module('myAppT').controller('analyticController',analyticController);
```

analyticController.$inject=['sharedService','commonService','$scope','session','$state','$sessionStorage'];

function analyticController(sharedService,commonService,$scope,session,$state,$sessionStorage){
     $scope.myChartObject = {};

```
    $scope.myChartObject.type = "PieChart";

    $scope.onions = [
        {v: "Onions"},
        {v: 3},
    ];

    $scope.myChartObject.data = {"cols": [
        {id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string"},
        {id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number"}
    ], "rows": [
        {c: [
            {v: "Mushrooms"},
            {v: 3},
        ]},
        {c: $scope.onions},
        {c: [
            {v: "Olives"},
            {v: 31}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Zucchini"},
            {v: 1},
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Pepperoni"},
            {v: 2},
        ]}
    ]};

    $scope.myChartObject.options = {
        'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night'
    };
```

}

In html

```
<div google-chart chart="myChartObject" style="height:600px; width:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Please, show us code you have written. Did you import all the things that this chart is using? Seems like not.

Comment: I did ,angular
        .module('myAppT', ['coreapp','ps.unsecured','ngFileUpload','ps.analytics','googlechart']);

Comment: You have added the dependency in the module, however it requires to import this thing. That lets angular to know that this dependency exists and it imports from specific path that is in import. Before the module might be an import. If you are using WebStorm it usually imports all the things you downloaded with `npm` automatically. Otherwise, you have to import this by your own.

Comment: Did you install this chart-module by your package manager? You might forgot about that. Also it should be announced in package.json. Another way, as they mentioned, you can add the CDN link, that means it will be downloaded from another resource. I recommend you to use the second link, since it is minified, it will'be less weight. It should be addad in the index.html between the <header> tags

Comment: I am using bower & gulp, If I check by view source, Looks like the chart has been included , <script src="../bower_components/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.js"></script>

Comment: if you added it by your own - delete it. It's a relative path that, as I can suppose, it's just not incuded, so use the path the `getting started` provided, because it's an external resource.

Comment: importing modules happens in the `.js` files. There it uses the relative paths to packages that compiles in one file while you build prod. version of application. Also, if it is not necessary for you to use Angular 1*, I'd recommend you to use 4th version, because it much better in all the things.

Comment: Its added by the gulp server,  I think its proper path as other js are loaded in the same fashion & also If I click on the JS it loads the javascript

Comment: Try to build the prod. version it might throw few errors. Once I got this, when dev. version was working while prod. wan't. And there were no errors in dev :)

Comment: I feel , if I do view source code is loaded might be something to do with css it might be not loaded or overriden by my application css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149619/discussion-between-sergey-gultyaev-and-kiran).